# Finding the closest printer to the client on the network

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, client, zebra-printers

I am working on an application that loads a set of printers from a text file:

```
 protected void LoadPrinterList()
    {

        string CSVFilePathName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
        string[] Fields;
        Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
        int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
        for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToLower(), typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("nameanddescription", typeof(string), "name +'-'+ description");
        dt.Columns.Add("ipandconnectionstring", typeof(string), "ip +'-'+ ConncetionStringID");
        DataRow Row;
        for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                Row[f] = Fields[f];
            dt.Rows.Add(Row);
        }

        string hostname = Request.UserHostName.Substring(0, 3);
        string[] name = Printerlist.SelectedValue.Split('-');
        //string plant = name[0].ToString();
        //string plantvalue = plant.Substring(0, 3);
        //if(hostname == plantvalue)
        //{
        Printerlist.DataTextField = "nameanddescription";
        Printerlist.DataValueField = "ipandconnectionstring";
        //}
        Printerlist.DataSource = dt;
        Printerlist.DataBind();


    }
```

The issue is most of these printers are in the plant and I need to find the closest label printer to the client, I am able to get the client information:

```
public static string DetermineCompName(string IP)
    {
        IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        IPHostEntry GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP);
        List<string> compName = GetIPHost.HostName.ToString().Split('.').ToList();
        return compName.First();
    }

string IP = Request.UserHostName;
string compName = CompNameHelper.DetermineCompName(IP);
```

I also have the IP address of each of the printers because I print using the IP address. My question is how can I based on the IP of the client and the IP of the printer find the closest one?

Is there any alternative workaround? I looked a lot online but could not find enough info on this.

Comment: simple answer - you can't, usually there is no relationship between distance and ip address, especially in internal LAN

Comment: The only possible thing I could think of here is to ping each one several times and then take the average of all the pings, and then whichever one is the lowest, you could GUESS that one is closest, but probably be wrong almost every time anyway..

Comment: I doubt there will be a way to do this http://superuser.com/questions/327417/is-it-possible-to-find-a-printers-physical-location-in-a-building-by-its-ip-adr

Comment: I imagine you could associate static IP addresses with coordinates, for both clients and printers, and write a script to determine the distance between the client and all printers, and then select the IP of the closest one. However it would be a pain to maintain all those coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In a corporate network, switches may be poled to associate devices with ports that have a known location. I have supported dozens of networks and never seen it done to the detail you requested. Theoretically you could though, if network support could keep an updated record of what switch ports go to what wall ports. Typically printers would only be in a few places on a level and you'd have one subnet per level. Many networks have a hint in their name or description of where they are located.

Alternatively, if this is not just day dreaming and you really need it, I'd look at a separate location aware system such as rfid asset tracking or even just have all printers use wifi. Enterprise wifi arrays can estimate device locations (I know Xirrus can do this and it works well enough for closest printer). EDIT: and then to get the location of the device, you use an SNMP query on the wifi array.